# Как вывести информацию из БД по категориям?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Я не могу понять как мне сделать следующее.

Я вывожу информацию из базы данных посредством следующего кода

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `terms`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
echo "<li><a href='mytest2.php?id_cat={$row['term_id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></li>";
}?>
```

он выводит из таблицы terms имена всех категорий и подкатегорий, на которые разделена моя информация, единым списком, а еще извлекает ид. номер каждой из них.

В базе данных есть еще одна таблица, называется taxonomy, которая содержит т.н. таксономию, то есть определяет, к какой категории относится та или иная подкатегория. Она содержит две колонки: одна - с номерами подкатегорий, а другая колонка - с номерами категорий, которым соответствуют те или иные подкатегории. Все номера соответствуют номерам первой таблицы terms.

Теперь вопрос, как мне с помощью таблицы taxonomy выводить списки подкатегорий из первой таблицы terms не сплошным списком все подряд, а только по определенной категории, напр. только все подкатегории категории 1 или 2 и т.д.? Очень благодарен всем, кто сможет чем-то помочь.

Comment: Не совсем понятна состав таблиц. Не могли бы Вы, так сказать, в наглядных образах...списочек основных колонок этих двух таблиц и внешних ключей.

Comment: Да я пытался посредством html изобразить, ничего не вышло...
Первая таблица состоит из колонок: 

ид.номер(term_id) || название категории/подкатегории(name)

категории и подкат. идут сплошным списком, без распределений. Вторая таблица состоит из колонок:

ид. номер подкатегории(term_id) || ид.номер категории, которой 
                                   соответствует подкатегория(parent)

Надеюсь, понятно.

Comment: [Вот][1] здесь прочитайте про рекурсивные запросы, заодно посмотрите как в таком случае выглядит внутренняя структура БД
  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/sql/43955/

Comment: Спасибо, хабр вещь! Обязательно прочту.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, вы используете 2 таблици что бы хранить категории и подкатегории. В данном случае достаточно одной таблицы (связь один ко многим)

`id | parentId | category | ....`

что бы получить все корневые категории нужно выполнить:

```
select * from tbl where parentId=0;
```

а что бы получить все подкатегории:

```
select * from tbl where parentId=1; // id родительской категории
```

всё просто.

пример заполнения таблици:

`1 | 0 | category1
2 | 0 | category2
3 | 1 | sub category1
4 | 2 | sub category2`

Comment: А если вложеность 10 например? xD

Comment: Да, это хороший способ, а вложенность у меня не превысит подкатегорий. Однако, учитывая то, что в данную неудачную таблицу уже занесено около тысячи пунктов информации, я и решаю вопрос как использовать именно ее.

Comment: >> @AlexWindHope А если вложеность 10 например? xD

А в чем сложность ?

`
1  | 0 | category1
2  | 1 | subcategory1
3  | 2 | subcategory2
4  | 3 | subcategory3
5  | 4 | subcategory4
6  | 5 | subcategory5
7  | 6 | subcategory6
8  | 7 | subcategory7
9  | 8 | subcategory8
10 | 9 | subcategory9
`

Comment: А запросец на выборку всех категорий и подкатегорий 1ой?

Как хрянить в БД я вкурсе, да и это 1 из самых убогих по производительности способов, ну да не суть, запросец к БД "накидайте" xD

Comment: >> 1 из самых убогих 
?

что то я не вижу вашего варианта. Или только потрындеть да и гаразды ?

Comment: Открываем гугл, ищем **nested sets**, много-много читаем. От чего-же только потрындеть, нет, а вот вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос - запросец пожалуйста для 10-ичной вложенности (а лучше для бесконечной ;)).

Не отвечаю я по той причине что ответ был бы, мягко говоря, поболее вашего и он был бы больше похож на большущую статью, заниматся этим нет ни времени ни желания.

Comment: И опять отсылка в гугл и никакого ответа. Ну приведите sql для бесконечной вложенности приведенного вами же решения ? (без использования триггеров xD)

Comment: Для этого необходимо писать собственный класс(функции) (примеры есть в интернете). @shurik - я вам написал **много-много читаем**, а вы открыли первое что попалось (а именно почти 100% - статью хабры) и уже все знаете.

Если бы вы поняли идею вы бы не задавали, простите, **идиотского** вопроса о том как сделать выборку бессконечной вложенности.

Вы думаете что я чисто абыб потролить пишу?

Я вам(и не только) дал пищу для ума как решить эту задачу лучше, а вы так относитесь к этому как-будто бы мне принцип убедить других что ваш ответ Г и не более того.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше бы вам сразу создать рекурсию, что бы потом не заморачиваться когда понадобиться больше 2-3ех вложенностей

```
function menu($id)
{
    $tree_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE parentId={$id}");
    while ($menu_tree = mysql_fetch_assoc($tree_res)) {
        echo "<li>{$menu_tree['category']}'><ul>";
        menu($menu_tree['id']);
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    return;
}
echo "<ul>";
menu(0);
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Только в таком случае, было бы чудесно, кэшировать результат ибо при большой вложенности или большом количестве категорий БД будет плохо. (т.к. php работает линейно - остальному коду тоже)

Comment: Конечно, каждый раз делать цикл запросов в базу не вариант, я через это прошел, сейчас кэширую : )

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но я вообще-то не то чтобы учусь пхп, а даже еще не решил, буду ли я его изучать или нет. Так что, нельзя ли пояснить, что и как здесь...

Comment: Пока не будете чего-либо знать, вам никто обьяснить не сможет.

Comment: Ну, чего-нибудь я уже знаю...

Comment: Советую посмотреть видео уроки PHP+MySQL для начинающих.Евгений Попов, достаточно не плохой старт изучения php + mysql.

Comment: Скажите хотя бы какие таблицы вы в этом коде используете, такие, которые использую я или ту, которую здесь советуют, из трех колонок: id|category|parentid

Comment: Здесь используются поля под вас id|category|parentid , единственное вам нужно в запросе изменить таблицу table на свою.

Comment: Выдало вот чего
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /www/elitno.net/s/t/studcomazov/home/site/test/mytest.php on line 23

Comment: Сравните данные полей и таблицы в Коде с вашей базой, Ошибка именно в этом.

Comment: Сравнил раз десять, все кроме разве большой буквы в parentId абсолютно соответствует :( все ж копипастом делается, вы ж понимаете...

Comment: Понятно что копипастом, но мне ведь не известно действительно ли ваша таблица с полями соответствует с моим кодом, может вы забыли подключиться к базе своей, код 100% рабочий. т.к. вы новичок, не побоюсь спросить вы действительно в sql запросе переименовали 'table' на свою таблицу ?=)

Comment: Если бы к базе небыло поключения, выдало бы ошибку, а то, что надо имя таблицы заменить я видел сразу...

Comment: В Любом случаи, где то есть косяк.